# Is it normal that when I run my flutter code the first time it is rederized 2 times? (I only use one class )

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. Something worries me, I don't know if it is normal. I know the code will render if the widget is of type `StateFulWidget`. But in this case, I have a `stateLessWidget` and for some reason it renders 2 times. is this normal?

this is my code:

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      print("main");
      return MaterialApp(title: 'Provider Example', initialRoute: '/', routes: {
        '/': (context) => Page2(),
      });
    }
  }

  class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
    Page2() {
      print("page2");
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container();
    }
  }
```

this is the output:

```
 Restarted application in 832ms.
 I/flutter ( 4439): main
 I/flutter ( 4439): page2    --> next two lines are the same, the widget is render again
 I/flutter ( 4439): main
 I/flutter ( 4439): page2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter build method is what creates and return your rendered widget on the screen, so the build must be called everytime something change in the UI, and it need to rebuild. According to the [Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html)

The build method will be called after:

- After calling initState.
- After calling didUpdateWidget.
- After receiving a call to setState.
- After a dependency of this State object changes (e.g., an InheritedWidget referenced by the previous build changes).
- After calling deactivate and then reinserting the State object into the tree at another location.

So even if you have a Stateless Widget, flutter can and will rebuild multiple times, this why you should avoid putting logic handlers inside your Widgets, specially the `build`, let this method as simple as possible with only what it actually needs to build the widget.

Also, during animations, transitions... Your widget will be rebuild a lot of times in order to perfom the animation. If you want to avoid unnecessary builds there's some ways you can do it, by making using of the `const` widgets, if you that a certain Widget won't change during runtime like a `Text('Hi')` this kind of Widget just need to be build once, so you can use a `const` keyword to it.

Comment: I didn't know about putting `const` so that the widget doesn't render. thank you very much for your answer, in other words this behavior is totally normal

Comment: Yes, of course that if you see that your build is being called like a 100x times, it means something may be wrong, anyway `const` and `final` keywords have a different meaning in dart, take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@jelenaaa.lecic/whats-the-difference-between-const-and-final-in-dart-c274db97f9fc) so you will understand better :)

Comment: can you please give me an example of using const inside a build? I get syntax errors.

Comment: The const keyword must be used with Widgets that depends on values that are know at compile time, which means that if you have a Text that shows the value of a variable that can change during Runtime, you will get error because that Widget can't be const. You can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1fIqdqwWw8) to understand better what const means

Comment: I understand but, in this case, I am getting errors https://i.imgur.com/CfhM7tO.jpg  for example I put `const SafeArea(..`

Comment: And which child do you have inside your SafeArea? can pls a screenshot?

Comment: I am very grateful for your help. In this case, I have a sidemenu (`drawer`), and since I don't want it to be redrawn, I put it `const` but I get syntax errors, also with my `stack`, but I don't understand why with a` Text` I don't I get error.
 https://i.imgur.com/nyioFBs.jpg

Comment: A drawer Widget can't be const, otherwise how you are going to open it  if the state of that Widget is supposed to never change and you need that state to change when you open, besides Flutter is smart enough to rebuild only the necessary Widgets when the build method is called, why are you afraid of that? Are you doing some heavy operation inside the build of the drawer?

Comment: A `stack` also cannot be const?